# Indefinite integral of a density function

Tags: wavefunction, probability, integration, density, calculus

Suppose that $\rho(x)=\frac{dm}{dx}$ is the linear density of a rod. Can we find the mass at each point of the rod by integrating $\rho(x)$, so that:$$m(x)=\int\rho(x)dx.$$ Can we do the same with probability density in quantum mechanics, so that:$$P(x)=\int|\Psi|^{2}dx$$ (assuming one dimensional wavefunction). In the case of probability density I think we can't because the probability in every point would be 0 because the position is a continuous variable. Any ideas?

Comment: What does “the mass at each point” mean?

Answer (score 2):

It's neither possible to find the *mass of a point* nor the (quantum) *probability in such a point*.

It **is** possible to find the mass of a small interval $\delta x$, located at $x$ as:

$$m(x,x+\delta x)=\int_x^{x+\delta x}\rho(x)\text{d}x$$

Similarly:

$$P(x,x+\delta x)=\int_x^{x+\delta x}|\Psi|^{2}\text{d}x$$

Note that in both cases, when $\delta x=0$, the integral returns $0$.

Comment: Notation like $m(x,x+\delta x)$ would be clearer; $m(\delta x)$ looks like there is no dependence on $x$.

Comment: @Gert So the indefinite integrals would also zero?

Comment: the indefinite integral makes no sense ,  or what do you call the indefinite Integral?

Comment: @adosar: the indefinite integral, is...erm... indefinite!

Comment: @G.Smith Agreed. Edit made. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can calculate indefinite integral of
$$ m(x)=\int\rho(x)dx $$
For simplicity lets say density is uniform along all rod, so integration result will be :
$$ m(x) = \rho\, x + m_o $$
where $m_o$ would be integration constant. The meaning of equation would be rod mass **until** point $x$ + integration constant. So semantically this integral is equivalent (up to integration constant) to a definite integral
$$\int_0^x\rho(x)dx$$
So in principle I would recommend too to work on definite integrals more, because in such case you

- Would not have to think about integration constant. In this simple example integration constant is just some value, but in general case it can be an arbitrary expression.
- You always will be forced to think about physical meaning first
  , because you must think about boundary conditions, i.e. integration limits. In most general case you can use definite integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+{\infty}}$ (For example probability of finding a particle in a whole universe, etc.)